# Powershell command Set-AzureStorageBlobContent ignore flag

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-blob-storage

I want to upload new blob to Azure storage account, but only of it doesn't already exist. I was wondering if there is any way to setup Set-AzureStorageBlobContent command to ignore already existing items, so I can achieve that in one operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to upload new blob to Azure storage account, but only of it doesn't already exist.

From the documentation of [Set-AzureStorageBlobContent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt617158(v=azure.98).aspx), it seems that there are not existing parameters that could be used to skip/ignore the existing blob while uploading the file to blob. As a workaround, we could use [Get-AzureStorageBlob](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt603751.aspx) cmdlet to check whether the blob is already existing before run Set-AzureStorageBlobContent cmdlet to upload file to blob.

```
try
{   
     $blob = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Blob $blobName -Container $containerName -Context $blobContext -ErrorAction Stop

     Write-Host "Blob is existing"
}
catch 
{
    # The blob doesn't exist
    # Add logic here 

    Write-Host "Blob Not Found"

    Write-Host "Start Upload Blob"

    Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -File $filename -Container $containerName -Blob $blobName -Context $blobContext 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer @FredHan. This is what I ended up doing. Also, you can be more specific on the catch statement: `catch [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.Common.ResourceNotFoundException]`